# Choose between two columns based on aggregate of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If `PEOPLE` are the same as in other rows but `COMPANY` is different, then give me `SERVICE_1`; if `PEOPLE` are the same like other rows and `COMPANY` are also the same then give me `SERVICE2`. How can I write code for this in T-SQL? Can it be achieved using the `row_number` clause?

Original data:

| PEOPLE | COMPANY | SERVICE_1 | SERVICE_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KRISH | AA | HYDRO | WATER |
| KRISH | BB | NULL | WATER |
| JOHN | CC | NULL | ROAD |
| JOHN | CC | NULL | ELECY |
| JOHN | CC | NULL | GAS |

Desired results:

| PEOPLE | COMPANY | SERVICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KRISH | AA | HYDRO |
| KRISH | BB | NULL |
| JOHN | CC | ROAD |
| JOHN | CC | ELECY |
| JOHN | CC | GAS |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a dozen ways to do this. One is you can count the distinct companies separately and then join, exposing the service with a CASE expression ([example](https://dbfiddle.uk/V267MbBE)):

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT PEOPLE, c = COUNT(DISTINCT COMPANY)
  FROM dbo.Something GROUP BY PEOPLE
)
SELECT cte.PEOPLE, s.COMPANY,
  SERVICE = CASE WHEN cte.c = 1 THEN s.SERVICE_2 ELSE s.SERVICE_1 END
FROM cte JOIN dbo.Something AS s
ON cte.PEOPLE = s.PEOPLE;
```